# Trying to insert a parameter on SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Query on Oracle SQL

```
SELECT LE.LLAMADA_ID,
       TO_CHAR(LE.FECHA_HORA_1, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA, 
       TO_CHAR(LE.FECHA_HORA_2, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_2, 
       LE.TECNICO_1 ID,
       T.DESCR Nombre, 
       COLA_1, 
       COLA_2
FROM QU_LLAMADA_EVENTO LE, 
     INVT_TECNICOS T
WHERE LE.FECHA_HORA_1 BETWEEN '16-jan-2019' AND '17-jan-2019' --CAMBIAR LAS FECHAS, SE PONEN UN DIA ANTES Y UN DIA DESPUES, Si quiero el 11 de enero pongo el 11 de enero el dia antes y el 12 de enero como dia despues 
AND LE.TECNICO_1 = T.ID
ORDER BY TECNICO_1, FECHA_HORA_1 ASC;
```

I'm a noob and I'm getting the following error

```
ORA-01858: se ha encontrado un carácter no numérico donde se esperaba uno numérico
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

I know that the problem is with the `To_Date` value, where should I put the `To_Date` value in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `FECHA_HORA_1` is a date (or timestamp) column, you can use a `to_date` this way, for example:

```
LE.FECHA_HORA_1 BETWEEN to_date ('16-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') and …
```

Here you can write the date in format you like, you just need to edit the format mask accordingly. Notice that I avoided to write the month like `'jan'`, because this is based on the language of you system.

An easier way, with no function call or formats may be the ANSI way:

```
LE.FECHA_HORA_1 BETWEEN date '2019-01-16' and …
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform your characters to date with `TO_DATE('17-jan-2019','dd-mon-yyyy')` :

```
SELECT LE.LLAMADA_ID,
       TO_CHAR(LE.FECHA_HORA_1, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA,
       TO_CHAR(LE.FECHA_HORA_2, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_2,
       LE.TECNICO_1 ID,
       T.DESCR Nombre,
       COLA_1,
       COLA_2
  FROM QU_LLAMADA_EVENTO LE
  JOIN INVT_TECNICOS T
    ON LE.TECNICO_1 = T.ID
 WHERE LE.FECHA_HORA_1 BETWEEN to_date('16-jan-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
   AND to_date('17-jan-2019', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
 ORDER BY TECNICO_1, FECHA_HORA_1 ASC;
```

Here are the different formats for TO_DATE() :
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: If you're going to provide a supporting link it's better to use [the official Oracle documentation portal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) rather than an unofficial source, unless you have reason to think the Oracle documentation is wrong or incomplete regarding the topic in question.